# How can I use induction to prove that this recursive definition is correct?

Tags: calculus, induction, recursion

How can I use induction to prove that this recursive definition is correct?

$f(n)=4n-2$ for $n≥1$

Recursive definition:

1) $f(1)=2$

2) $f(n)=f(n-1)+4$

Now I have to use induction to prove that the recursive definition is correct but I don't know how to do it since $f(n)$ is not equal to anything.

Comment: In the 'usual ' way, that is show that it's true for the base case. Then assume that it holds for $n $. Use this tohether with the recursive  defininition to show the formula holds for $n+1$.

Comment: If the goal is proving that $f$ satisfies the recursion, take also into account that you can prove it without induction. Just substitute the definition in (1) and (2): $f(1)=4\cdot 1-2=2$. $f(n)=4n-2=4(n-1)-2+4=f(n-1)+4$. If proving that that is the only solution of the recurrence, then induction is necessary.

Comment: @user560980 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be defined as in your question and let $g$ be defined recursively by $g(1)=2$ and $g(n)=g(n-1)+4$.

Then it is enough to prove by induction that $g(n)=f(n)$ for positive integers.

The base case is just the observation that $g(1)=2=f(1)$.

Now the induction step:

If $g(n)=f(n)=4n-2$ then $g(n+1)=g(n)+4=4n-2+4=4n+2=f(n+1)$.

Comment: Isn't $g(2)=6=f(2)$?

Comment: @user560980. Yes. It should have been $g(1)=2=f(1)$. I will repair. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We have that for the base case

- $f(1)=2$ by recursive relation
- $f(1)=4-2=2$ by formula

for induction step we assume true

- $f(n)=f(n-1)+4=4n-2$

and we need to prove that

- $f(n+1)=f(n)+4=4(n+1)-2$

Comment: How can I prove the last thing?